# Route parameter with regular expression to capture everything

Tags: node.js, express

In my Node.js (+express) application I expect the following requests:

```
GET /images/foo1/id500/abc5
GET /images/foo2/id540
GET /images/id500/foo800
```

In other words the requests will have constant prefix `/images/` and some additional random path that I need to capture.

```
app.get("/images/:foo(*)", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.foo);
  res.send(req.params.foo);
});
```

The code above does exactly what I want, but if I put "." (any character) to the regexp then it stops working...

The following code does not work:

```
app.get("/images/:foo(.*)", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.foo);
  res.send(req.params.foo);
});
```

Why using `:foo(.*)` does not give desired result while `:foo(*)` or `:foo(\\w*)` work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match regular expressions, you must use regexp matching. Here's the difference:

```
 app.get(/a/, (req, res) => { // Matches anything with an “a” in it, such as /xax.
 app.get('a', (req, res) => { // matches exactly /a
```

You can rewrite your example as a regexp, remember to escape the `/`:

```
app.get(/\/images\/:foo(.*)/, (req, res) => {
```

Comment: But I use parenthesis to embed regular expression and link it with parameter. Anyway, I tried you approach and it still does not work for me.